# Windows clipboard manager with shortcuts for most-recently-copied items

Tags: windows, clipboard

I use a Mac, and many of the Mac clipboard managers allow one to assign shortcuts to each of the most-recently-copied items.  I use CopyLess, and here I've assigned CMD-OPT-1 through CMD-OPT-0 to the 10 most-recently-copied items (see screenshot at bottom).

This is extraordinarily handy if I have say, a form with several fields, whose info. I need to copy into the fields of second form.  And I don't need to open the Copyless clipboard to use these shortcuts.

I have some colleagues who use PCs, and they would like to have a Windows clipboard manager with this feature.  I did some searching, and the only one it seems *might* do this is ClipboardMaster (Ditto doesn't seem to have it).

But it's hard to tell from their instructions.  It sounds like, if you have the numlock key on, you can paste entries 2-10 using second Alt (is that right Alt?) + 2 to 0 without having to open it.  But what about the first entry? Seems like you'd need to use Ctrl-V for that, which is inconvenient if you want to paste the last n entries.  E.g., if you want to paste the last four, you should be able to hold down the second Alt key, and then hit 1,2,3,4 in succession, not Ctrl-V, then second Alt + 2,3,4.

https://www.clipboardmaster.com/instructions/use-clipboard-master/copy-collect-and-paste/paste.html :

[image]

Anyone have experience doing this with ClipboardMaster—or, more broadly, know of a Win clipboard manager that does this seamlessly?

I'd also like it to have the other basic clipboard manager features, like being able to store at least the last 1,000 clipboard entries, and having those be searchable.

[image]

Comment: **[Arsclip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/)** might come close to that (see "Using Arsclip" in [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-use-arsclip-to-enhance-the-windows-clipboard/). Hit Ctrl-Shift-Z to open the popup, then the number/letter of the clip you want to paste (last 15, so 0-9 and A-F). Would that fit your needs?

Comment: @Izzy  Thanks.  Almost but not quite.  What I'm looking for is something where you can hit the shortcuts directly, without the extra step of having to open the popup.

Comment: Thought so, hence just a comment. Hopefully someone else can come up with a solution then. Best luck!